# Tableone unable to process factors from a survey svydesign object

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to generate a table one summary using the tableone package where the data input is a survey design object made with the survey package. According to tableone documentation, this should be possible and in fact, it works on my colleagues' workspace. Tableone is able to process the continuous variables but not factors. Below is a reproducible example

```
library(survey, tableone)
age<- c(55,66,77,33,44)
gender<-c("Male","Male","Female","Male","Female")
weights<-c(2.3,1.0,3.0,2.3,1.0)

df<- data.frame(age,gender,weights)
svy <- svydesign(id = ~0, data = df, weights=~weights)
t1 <- svyCreateTableOne(data = svy, vars=c("age", "gender"))
```

I get an error saying: "Error in Summary.factor(c(3L, 1L), na.rm = TRUE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors"

This persists regardless of whether I leave the 'gender' column as character or whether I change it to a factor prior to creating svy1.

I am running R ver 3.4.4 on RStudio 1.1.442.

Anyone face this issue or have advice on resolving this? Thanks!

Comment: in your `t1 <- svyCreateTableOne(data = svy, vars=c("age", "gender"))` if you put `t1 <- svyCreateTableOne(data = svy, vars=c("age", "gender"), factorVars = "gender")` does that resolve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: The issue must be something in the `svy` object. `CreateTableOne(vars=c("age","gender"),data=df)` works fine with both categorical and quantitative variables.

Comment: It's really strange because if I use the svytable function, it works fine which is suggesting to me that the svy object is ok and understands that gender is a categorical: `svytable(~gender, svy)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the variable "weights" to something else (e.g. "ps_Weights") and it will run.

```
library(survey)
library(tableone)
age<- c(55,66,77,33,44)
gender<-c("Male","Male","Female","Male","Female")
ps_weights<-c(2.3,1.0,3.0,2.3,1.0)

df<- data.frame(age,gender,ps_weights)
svy <- svydesign(id = ~0, data = df, weights=~ps_weights)
t1 <- svyCreateTableOne(data = svy, vars=c("age", "gender"))
print(t1)

                Overall      
n 9.60
age (mean (sd)) 56.60 (19.03)
gender = Male (%) 5.6 (58.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works if you drop the categorical variable from the list of variables you provide to `svyCreateTableOne`:

```
> t1 <- svyCreateTableOne(data = svy, vars=c("age", "weights")) 
> t1

                      Overall      
  n                    9.60        
  age (mean (sd))     56.60 (19.03)
  weights (mean (sd))  2.25 (0.79)
```

From my understanding of the `tableone` package, you have to examine your categorical and quantitative variables separately. If you want to split by gender, add it as `strata`:

```
> t1 <- svyCreateTableOne(data = svy, vars=c("age", "weights"), strata=c("gender")) 
> t1
                     Stratified by gender
                      Female        Male          p      test
  n                    4.00          5.60                    
  age (mean (sd))     68.75 (20.21) 47.93 (15.99)  0.205     
  weights (mean (sd))  2.50 (1.22)   2.07 (0.61)   0.552
```

Comment: I agree with the first part - tableone works perfectly with the continuous vars. With regards to the second part - I actually still get the same error when using the code you quoted above, stratifying by gender. As an aside, I think I still should be able to use categorical variables in the tableone and report weighted frequencies. In fact the subset function svyCreateCatTable is supposed to do just that, but also doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yep, I just looked into the code and it does look like `svyCreateTableOne` is supposed to construct the values for the categorical and quantitative separately, and then combine into a `TableOne` object... and it's not doing that for your data. Have you tried contacting the package author? There might be a bug.